# Module parse failed using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi I am student developer. I facing an error like this

> ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16 Module parse failed: Unexpected token
>   (5:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
>   currently no loaders are  configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | import App from
>   '../src/components/App' |
>
> > ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("app")); i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

I am starting to learn webpack what it is but I do not have enough information about solving this. Could you help me at this issue  to solve ?

package.json Dev Part :

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
```

My webconfig :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.export = {
    entry : './src/index.js',
    output : {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'/dist')   ,
        filename:'index_bundle.js' 
    },
    module:{
        rules : [{
            test : /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use : {
                loader : 'babel-loader'
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from '../src/components/App'

// Error is he
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("app"));
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell webpack that you are compiling react. You need to update your rule as:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry : './src/index.js',
    output : {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'/dist')   ,
        filename:'index_bundle.js' 
    },
    module:{
        rules : [{
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["react"]
          }
       }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works correctly with `npm install babel-loader@7 babel-core` command.

Comment: Glad to know that it was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your webpack configuration, which is causing this issue.

1. There is a typo error. Change `module.export` to `module.exports` (This one drive me crazy man :P)
2. As @Muhammad mentioned, you need to mention webpack to compile the `react`. So, I have added `'@babel/react'` as presets for the `babel-loader`.

Below is the webpack that is working for me:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry : './src/index.js',
    output : {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'/dist')   ,
        filename:'index_bundle.js' 
    },
    module:{
        rules : [{
            test : /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            '@babel/react',
            
          ]
        }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried and your code works correctly. Thanks your advice. I checked your answer as an useful.

Comment: @EmreSert Glad that it helps you